# Extract filenames from fileInfos

Tags: c#

I have `FileInfo[]` fileInfos
I want to populate
`string[]` filesNames and `List<string>` fileNamesList using LINQ expression, how should I do it?

Comment: Time to start learning LINQ, don't you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) has a `Name` property, so

```
var fileNamesList = fileInfos.Select(fi => fi.Name).ToList();
var filesNames = fileInfos.Select(fi => fi.Name).ToArray();
```

I don't see why you would need both a `List` and an array though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = fileInfos.Select(fi => fi.Name).ToList();
var arr = fileInfos.Select(fi => fi.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> filesNamesList = fileInfos.Select(fi => fi.Name).ToList();
string[] filesNames = filesNamesList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

`var fileList = fileInfos.Select(f => f.Name).ToList();`